# IP issues in Microsoft Azure

Tags: c#, sql, azure

I have set up a Microsoft Azure SQL Database and added the connection string to my C# program. After doing some research I have found that you need to add individual IPs to the firewall rules in Microsoft Azure. The only issue I have with this is that my clients will be using the software from different locations which will change daily meaning they will have different IPs all the time. Is there a way I can get around this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What kind of application it is? Console or WPF/WinForm? Are you embedding the connection string in the application itself?

Comment: What "problem"? Updating the firewall? Updating the code? It's not clear what problem you are facing.

Comment: It's a Windows Desktop Application. I've added the connection string for the SQL Server Database into the app.config file. The problem I am facing is that the software will need to be accessed from various locations so is there a way I could add a connection rule to the firewall so that only certain computers can access the database rather than using an IP? Thanks.

Comment: No you can't do it by computer name. The way you'd normally do this is with certificates but SQL Server doesn't support that. Are all these clients on the same corporate network? or are they all completely different people? The other way around this is to set up a VPN to the SQL Server bit it gets a bit complicated

Answer (score 2):

Easiest (but certainly not recommended) approach would be to allow all IP addresses to connect to your SQL Database.

Better approach would be to not allow direct connections from your WPF C# application to your database. Instead create a web service and have your application talk to this web service and let the web service talk to the database.

Answer (score 0):

As being said, direct access to the database from your app is not a good idea. Putting connection string into your app.config is a security issue. Anybody will be able to connect to the database and read/manipulate data outside of your application. Whatever restrictions you put in your application will be null and void when connecting directly to your database via connection string. And you'll be only left with security provided by SQL user.